# CSS Force span not to have its parent style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a span including multiple spans:

```
<span id="sp9">
   <span class="comment">/*
     <span class="number">  11     </span>* some text
     <span class="number">  12     </span>* -------------------
     <span class="number">  13     </span>* other text
     <span class="number">  14     </span>* some stuff
     <span class="number">  15     </span>*/
   </span>
</span>
```

In JavaScript code I am doing this:

```
function highlight(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "gray";
}
```

In the CSS file I have the style of the class `number` like this:

```
.number {
    color: DarkCyan;
    background-color: none !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
}
```

When the JavaScript function is executed, the `numbers` are included in the background color change which I don't want to happen.

I tried logging the background color of all `numbers` and it was empty (no background color) so I know they don't have it.

How can I force the `numbers` not to have any background color?

I am new to these types of stuff so excuse me. I have looked at other questions here and I believe I might need to change a major thing in here.

I have tried using `div` instead of `span` which worked but in the display the `div`s were on separate lines. I changed their `display` to `inline-block` and got them to be in the same line, but the highlighting started behaving just like the spans.

Any ideas?

Comment: add `!important` to child elements style. i.e `display:inline-block !important;` then it will ignore parent's css rule for display property

Comment: so in the css file, you can't do #sp9 .comment .number { background: none;  } doesn't work?

Comment: @guyfawkes I have tried it, still same :\

Comment: can you use jQuery or does it have to be java script?

Comment: I think the key point here is that setting the background to none, makes it transparent, so the background of the parent element shows through - it's not that they have the same style

Comment: @Keith The IDs are generated automatically by an external program so I cant set them like that. However, I tried it manually for this `span` and it still didn't work

Comment: @SpoonMeiser THANK YOU. I realized my mistake now. Just did it and worked amazing. THANKS

Comment: Since you said you're new to this stuff... If you were to inspect the `span.number` in the CSS panel of your browser's dev tools, you'd be able to see and adjust the CSS. At that point, it may have been clearer (no pun intended but proud of it now!) that those elements were transparent and allowing the parent's background to come through.

Comment: @Will I logged them and printed them out to the console and it never came to me that no color meant transparent >.< I'm mostly C++/C# programmer, and webdev newbie xD

Comment: C++/C# programmer indeed if you were logging elements to the console to sort out visual issues. :D Check this out https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/ Good luck!

Comment: @Will Haha, yeah I do inspect elements very often, this just slipped. Newbie's mistake haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow one of the 2 approaches

- Specify a default background color for the `number` class ( As you are setting it to transparent by setting it to `none`)
- Enclose the pre and post text into a span and specify a background color to them instead of the parent.

**#1**

```js
function highlight(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "gray";
}

highlight("sp9");
```

```css
.number {
    color: DarkCyan;
    background: white;
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
}
```

```html
<span id="sp9">
   <span class="comment">/*
     <span class="number">  11     </span>* some text
     <span class="number">  12     </span>* -------------------
     <span class="number">  13     </span>* other text
     <span class="number">  14     </span>* some stuff
     <span class="number">  15     </span>*/
   </span>
</span>
```

**#2**

```css
.number {
    color: DarkCyan;
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
}

.post-text {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<span id="sp9">
   <span class="comment"><span class="post-text">/*</span>
     <span class="number">  11     </span><span class="post-text">* some text</span>
     <span class="number">  12     </span><span class="post-text">* -------------------</span>
     <span class="number">  13     </span><span class="post-text">* other text</span>
     <span class="number">  14     </span><span class="post-text">* some stuff</span>
     <span class="number">  15     </span><span class="post-text">*/</span>
   </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you I got what I wanted, I was forcing it to none so it was transparent. I will force it to the page's background then. Thanks again